# Java access to remote db, user permissions

Tags: java, database, sqlexception

i want to access my remote datebase with jdbc from java:

```
public class DB_Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          Connection con = null;
          String username = "my_username";
          String password = "my_passwort";
          String server = "www.example.de"; //remote server address
          String db = "usr_web123_1";
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+server+"/"+db;
          try {
              con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
          } catch (SQLException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
   }

}
```

Thus I a get an: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'web123'@'dslb-234-068-089-173.pools.arcor-ip.net' (using password: YES)

I think it has something to do with user permission on the server. But this is only a webspace, so i haven't got root-permission on the server.

What possibility is there to get access to the db?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your credentials are correct, theres probably no way to remote access database except from the instance running the database. Probably the remote access is forbidden.
Ask your provider if theres a way ;)

Comment: Is there a common way to provide an interface? My problem doesn't look so special, that nobody has provided a solution for this. Is forbidden acces the default case for webspaces?

Comment: Its not a problem of "able to" its a problem of security. If your webspace does not provide direct remote access to the databases you probably wont get access if the provider dont want it (and yes its more or less the default). I dont know which provider you are using but maybe he provides some kind of UI to edit the data (phpmyadmin?). You could write your own UI and deploy it on your webspace (that would be local access) and write data from there to the database. But unless you implement some kind of authorization everybody could write data to your database!

Comment: Yes, there is a phpmyadmin-Interface. Are there UI, I can use for my purpose?

Comment: I would recommend to use some IaaS provider (e.g. Amazon Webservices) and configuring your own database on your own risk. There you can do what you want :)